# Is it possible to have pixel hinting on vector graphics of an unknown size on a webpage?

Tags: svg, browser, fonts, type-hinting, vector-graphics

Glyphs in typefaces for screens often use hinting to align the shapes with the screen pixels so the result has sharp edges. Could I do something similar with arbitrary vector graphics on a webpage?

I know that I can align lines with pixels in a vector graphic, but that works at only the default size and its integer multiples. My idea is that the graphic would have hinting similar to what is used in typefaces to have sharp edges at all sizes.

This could be used for icons, text decorations or list item markers and for prerendered math formulae. In the case of a formula, the hinting would be automatically derived from the hinting of glyphs in the typeface used to render the formula.

Comment: Your question got me contemplating the subject with my feet on my desk. Although I encountered (and corrected) enough misaligned graphics, I never heard of 'pixel hinting'. Now that I do (read [How does pixel hinting work?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/32134) and [how-to-hint-variable-fonts](https://googlefonts.github.io/how-to-hint-variable-fonts/) and some others), I think it is a great subject to discuss on *StackExchange* not on SO. Unless you have some code setup or [reprex] with issues that need to be resolved. Sorry, that's how SO works...

Comment: sounds like you're looking for the shape-rendering property.

Answer (score 2):

SVG supports two CSS properties for pixel alignment optimization:

- [shape-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) handles edges of grafic primitives and the anti-aliasing applied.
- [text-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-rendering) handles the positioning of glyphs and the way font-internal rendering hints are applied.

Both are presentation attributes that can be used either in CSS styles or as XML attributes.

Both act under the caveat that the values of the properties are treated as hints, with the browser free to interpret them the optimal way.

There is not one solution that will work out in  every situation. A prominent case is text rendered at an angle to a horizontal line, or text along a curved path. If you choose to `optimizeLegibility`, the individual glyphs will often be slightly rotated and moved away from their precise position and may not remain in a straight line. If you choose `geometricPrecision`, especially small fonts may suffer from degrading legibility.

For grafic primitives, the most pronounced effects show up for narrow (curved) strokes and for multiple grafical primitives that have a common edge (think two rectangles next to each other). There, hinting (to turn antialiasing on - `geometricPrecision` or off - `crispEdges`) may help in some situations, but in others you still have to resort to wider strokes or overlapping areas.

Another fallback technique may include restricting the scaling of a grafic to only some multiples or fractions of integers, so that you still have control over pixel alignment.